# How to store selected rows into tuple?

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

I have following code to select rows from a SQLite database:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

csat = lite.connect('Tanuloim.db')

with csat:
    hely = csat.cursor()

    for evflym in range (5, 6):
    hely.execute('select count() from tanulo where evf=? and tannyelv="Sr"', (evflym,))
    xlegnagySr = (hely.fetchone()[0])

    hely.execute('select count() from tanulo where evf=? and tannyelv="Hu"', (evflym,))
    xlegnagyHu = (hely.fetchone()[0])


    hely.execute('select count() from munkadbnevsora where evf=?', (evflym,))
    ylegnagy = (hely.fetchone()[0])

    print ('Ennyi magyar ötödikes tanuló van - xlegnagyHu:', xlegnagyHu)
    print ('Ennyi szerb ötödikes tanuló van - xlegnagySr:', xlegnagySr)
    print ('Ennyi munkadarab van az ötödikben - ylegnagy:', ylegnagy)
    print ('evfolyam:', evflym)

    hely.execute('select tanuloneve from tanulo where evf=? and tannyelv="Sr"', (evflym,))
    """" This is returned as a tuple, let it named tuple1. """
    for x in range (0, xlegnagySr):
        print (hely.fetchone()[0])

    hely.execute('select munkdbnevesr from munkadbnevsora where evf=?', (evflym,)')
    """" This is returned as a tuple, let it named tuple2. """
    for y in range (0, ylegnagy):
        print (hely.fetchone()[0])
```

Example for tuple1:

```
[('tanulo1',), ('tanulo2',), ('tanulo3',), ... ('tanulo19',)]
```

where the number of 19 in tanulo19 indicate that that xlegnagySr=19.

Example for tuple2:

```
[('munkdbnevesr1',), ('munkdbnevesr2',), ('munkdbnevesr3',),... ('munkdbnevesr13',)]
```

where 13 indicate that that `ylegnagy=13`.

The desired result should look like this:

```
thirdtable = [('tanulo1','munkadbnevesr1'),('tanulo1','munkadbnevesr2'),.‌​..('tanulo1','munkad‌​bnevesr13'),('tanulo‌​2','munkadbnevesr1')‌​,('tanulo2','munkadb‌​nevesr2'),...,('tanu‌​lo2','munkadbnevesr1‌​3'), ...,('tanulo19','munkadbnevesr13')]
```

where numbers 19 and 13 indicates that that xlegnagySr=19 and ylegnagy=13.

So what I want is this: to insert into third database table some combined values from tuple1 and tuple2.

I think the way for this is to save sql queries into tuple1 and tuple2 and then in a for statement insert values into third table.

To do something that is opposite to this:

```
# Larger example that inserts many records at a time
purchases = [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
             ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
             ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
            ]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchases)
```

How can I do this?

The schema for my database follows:

```
CREATE TABLE munkadbnevsora (
  sorszam integer CONSTRAINT ek_munkadbnevsora PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,
  evf integer NOT NULL ,
  negyedev integer NOT NULL ,
  munkdbnevehu text NOT NULL COLLATE nocase ,
  munkdbnevesr text NOT NULL COLLATE nocase
);
CREATE TABLE tanulo (
  az integer CONSTRAINT ek_tanulo PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,
  azszam integer UNIQUE NOT NULL ,
  tanuloneve text NOT NULL COLLATE nocase ,
  tannyelv text NOT NULL COLLATE nocase ,
  evf integer NOT NULL ,
  tagozat text NOT NULL COLLATE nocase ,
  osztfonok text NOT NULL COLLATE nocase 
);
CREATE TABLE egyedimunkadb (
  az integer CONSTRAINT ek_egyedimunkadb PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  tanulo_akie_amunkadb text NOT NULL REFERENCES tanulo (azszam) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
  munkadb_anevsorbol integer NOT NULL REFERENCES munkadbnevsora (sorszam) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
  jegy integer ,
  indoklas text
);
```

So I realized that that my python code and example of tuple2 is wrong, because the desired data filled into third table, which has the name 'egyedimunkadb' should look like this:

```
egyedimunkadb = [(1,'tanulo1',1),(2,'tanulo1',2),.‌​..(13,'tanulo1',13),(14,'tanulo‌​2',1)‌​,(15,'tanulo2',2),...,(26,'tanu‌​lo2',1‌​3), ...,(N,'tanulo19',19)]
```

where N is a number I do not know now.

Finally it works!
I put the following code of @CL. into python script:

```
hely.execute('INSERT INTO egyedimunkadb(tanulo_akie_amunkadb, munkadb_anevsorbol) SELECT tanuloneve, sorszam FROM tanulo CROSS JOIN munkadbnevsora WHERE tanulo.evf = ? AND munkadbnevsora.evf = ? AND tanulo.tannyelv = "Sr" ', (evflym, evflym))
```

and it populates the third database table with data as I expected.

Best, Pál

Comment: And how should the values be combined? Show some examples for the original `tuple1`/`tuple2` values and the desired result.

Comment: I added examples for the original tuple1/tuple2 and the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [INSERT statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) can accept a query. In this case, you want all possible combinations, which is a cross join:

```sql
INSERT INTO egyedimunkadb(tanulo_akie_amunkadb, munkadb_anevsorbol)
SELECT tanulo, sorszam
FROM tanulo
CROSS JOIN munkadbnevsora
WHERE tanulo.evf = ?
  AND munkadbnevsora.evf = ?
  AND tanulo.tannyelv = 'Sr';
```

Comment: I added SQL schema of my database, and I apologize because I just realized that that desired data in the third database table should look like different.

Comment: The autoincrement values are generated automatically.

Comment: I should put this insert statement above into my python code, because the tables 'tanulo' and 'munkadbnevsora' are filled with data later and not at creation of the database. So, when I insert datas into those first two tables, then I should run my python script to insert combined values into third database table, the 'egyedimunkadb' table. Right?

Comment: You should execute the INSERT when you want to insert those rows.

Comment: You mean that that it is not necesarily need to execute the INSERT from my python script, but can run in SQLite3 CLI?

Comment: And I still get not an answer for my first question: How to store selected rows into tuple?

Comment: Thanks! In the INSERT statement there is the 'tanulo' column name which does not exist. There should be the 'tanuloneve' column name instead. When I run this INSERT statement with the value '5' instead of '?' marks, I get Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed message, but this is another issue. Thanks again!

Comment: It works, finally, with your help! Thank you very much, @CL. !